# Adding a drive and OS to existing system, with full drive encryption

Tags: ubuntu, whole-drive-encryption

Current state:  Laptop with 1 TB encrypted drive running Ubuntu 16.04.

Would like a add a new 2 TB drive that is also encrypted and install 20.04 on it. Would like to keep the 16.04 alive till I have used 20.04 for a few months.

I came across these instructions: https://www.erianna.com/adding-an-secondary-encrypted-drive-with-lvm-to-ubuntu-linux/

Questions:

1. Would it be good to follow those instructions, especially given that
   I intend to install 20.04 on the new drive?
2. Or should I remove the 1 TB drive, add the new drive and install
   20.04 on it (and verify correctness).  Then put both drives and boot -- and then do what to get an unified view of the two separately encrypted drives?
3. Or should I just add the new drive, boot from a 20.04 USB and
   install on the new drive, with the installation steps taking care of
   whatever would need to be done?  If so, what would be the options to
   select during the install?

Boot system is UEFI.  Below are the first few lines from `cryptsetup luksDump` and the output from `lsblk`, `blkid`, and `df -h`

```
sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/nvme0n1p3
  Version:      1
  Cipher name:  aes
  Cipher mode:  xts-plain64
  Hash spec:    sha256

sudo lsblk
    NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
    nvme0n1                   259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk
      nvme0n1p3               259:3    0 952.9G  0 part
        nvme0n1p3_crypt       253:0    0 952.9G  0 crypt
           ubuntu--vg-root    253:1    0 867.5G  0 lvm   /
           ubuntu--vg-swap_1  253:2    0  63.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
      nvme0n1p1               259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
      nvme0n1p2               259:2    0   488M  0 part  /boot

sudo blkid
    /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt: UUID="xyz1" TYPE="LVM2_member"
    /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="xyz2" TYPE="ext4"
    /dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="xyz3" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="xyz10"
    /dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="xyz4" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="xyz8"
    /dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="xyz5" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="xyz9"
    /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="xyz6" TYPE="swap"
    /dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="xyz7" PTTYPE="gpt"

df -h
    Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev                          32G     0   32G   0% /dev
    tmpfs                        6.3G   58M  6.3G   1% /run
    /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  854G  659G  152G  82% /
    tmpfs                         32G  452M   31G   2% /dev/shm
    tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
    tmpfs                         32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    /dev/nvme0n1p2               473M  136M  313M  31% /boot
    /dev/nvme0n1p1               511M   24M  488M   5% /boot/efi
    tmpfs                        6.3G  124K  6.3G   1% /run/user/11098
```

Comment: In order to play safe I would select item #2, remove the current drive and install the new system in the new drive. After reconneting, it would be straightforward to run `sudo update-grub` in the system that boots and that way get menu entries also for the other version. But if you have a good backup, you should also dare to install Ubuntu 20.04 into the new drive without disconnecting the old drive. I have done that too. Details will also depend on the boot mode (UEFI or BIOS) and of the partition table (GUID or MSDOS).

Comment: Original question now includes information about the boot (UEFI) and drives. Under method #2, I understand that the "boot sector" on both drives are not encrypted and so `sudo update grub` would be able to create an unified menu.  But what would need to be  done to be able to decrypt both drives with the same password during boot? (I know about `cryptsetup luksOpen` followed by `mount` to access an encrypted drive, but would like to be able to decrypt both drives during boot with the same password.)